# How to automatically close the quick fix window when leaving a file?

Tags: vim

I use a plugin in vim to compile Tex files. When there are errors on compilation, they are all displayed in a quick fix window at the bottom of the screen.

When I want to leave a file I'm working on (`:q`, `:wq`, etc) the quickfix window can be annoying because it stays open after I left the buffer of the file I was working on, forcing me to `:q` on the quick fix window too.

Is there a way to tell vim to immediately execute `:close` when I use `:q`? I've tried several autocmds, but to no avail.

Comment: Would `:ccl` be helpful?

Comment: ``:ccl`` is exactly the same as ``:cclose``...

Comment: @Tomalak:  It does not: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su

Comment: Well, I disagree with that post and most of those that it links to. Questions about say, PHP, are akin to asking about road signs on a site about driving really well. OTOH, you wouldn't ask how to replace a car headlamp on the same site, any more than you'd ask here about how to change the batteries in your keyboard -- which you need to do when you're programming a lot. IDE questions are of a completely different ilk, _and_ `vim` is by no means restricted to the programming world anyway.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Add to your `.vimrc` file

```
aug QFClose
  au!
  au WinEnter * if winnr('$') == 1 && &buftype == "quickfix"|q|endif
aug END
```

Warning: this will close vim if the quickfix window is the only window visible (and only tab).

Comment: You made my day

Comment: Note to anyone using this script, it will only close if the last window open is the quickfix. If you open two different files both with a relative quickfix window in and you close one of the files, its correspondent quickfix window will remain in the screen.

Answer (score 3):

The command `:qa` will quit all open windows.

Answer (score 1):

To properly close even multiple quickfix/location/help windows automatically when leaving file (`:q`, `:wq`, etc.) add following code to your .vimrc:

```
" s:NextNormalWindow() {{{2
function! s:NextNormalWindow() abort
    for i in range(1, winnr('$'))
        let buf = winbufnr(i)

        " skip unlisted buffers
        if !buflisted(buf)
            continue
        endif

        " skip temporary buffers with buftype set
        if getbufvar(buf, '&buftype') != ''
            continue
        endif

        " skip the preview window
        if getwinvar(i, '&previewwindow')
            continue
        endif

        " skip current window
        if i == winnr()
            continue
        endif

        return i
    endfor

    return -1
endfunction

" s:QuitIfOnlyWindow() {{{2
function! s:QuitIfOnlyWindow() abort
    let l:buftype = getbufvar(winbufnr(winnr()), "&buftype")
    if l:buftype != "quickfix" && l:buftype != "help"
        return
    endif

    " Check if there is more than one window
    if s:NextNormalWindow() == -1
        " Check if there is more than one tab page
        if tabpagenr('$') == 1
            " Before quitting Vim, delete the special buffer so that
            " the '0 mark is correctly set to the previous buffer.
            " Also disable autocmd on this command to avoid unnecessary
            " autocmd nesting.
            if winnr('$') == 1
                if has('autocmd')
                    noautocmd bdelete
                endif
            endif
            quit
        else
            " Note: workaround for the fact that in new tab the buftype is set
            " too late (and sticks during this WinEntry autocmd to the old -
            " potentially quickfix/help buftype - that would automatically
            " close the new tab and open the buffer in copen window instead
            " New tabpage has previous window set to 0
            if tabpagewinnr(tabpagenr(), '#') != 0
                let l:last_window = 0
                if winnr('$') == 1
                    let l:last_window = 1
                endif
                close
                if l:last_window == 1
                    " Note: workaround for the same bug, but w.r.t. Airline
                    " plugin (it needs to refresh buftype and status line after
                    " last special window autocmd close on a tab page
                    if exists(':AirlineRefresh')
                        execute "AirlineRefresh"
                    endif
                endif
            endif
        endif
    endif
endfunction

" autoclose last open location/quickfix/help windows on a tab
if has('autocmd')
    aug AutoCloseAllQF
        au!
        autocmd WinEnter * nested call s:QuitIfOnlyWindow()
    aug END
endif
```

This does not have problems with new tab opening from within quickfix window.